# Retrieve values from one observable when an event happens in another observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have two streams.

- values
- buttonPresses

Every time a value changes, I get that value in my value stream.

Every time I press a button, I get an event in the button stream.

I want to do something when I get an event in the buttonPresses stream, with the latest value in the values stream. e.g. Make an API call.

However, I do not want something to happen every time a value changes.

I think this is a "thinking in observables" problem. Here's the actual code I'm struggling with.

```
/**
 * Provides a stream of POSTCODE_LOOKUP action events
 * @type {Object}
 */
export let PostcodeLookupActionsStream = Actions.stream
    .filter( action => action.key === KEYS.POSTCODE_LOOKUP );

/**
 * Provides a stream of values from a post code input field.
 * @type {Object}
 */
export let PostCodeValueStream = Actions.stream
    .filter( action => action.key === KEYS.POSTCODE_CHANGE )
    .map( action => action.payload.postcode )
    .shareReplay(1);

// Combine the two streams....?
export let PostCodeLookupStream = Rx.Observable
    .merge(PostCodeValueStream, PostcodeLookupActionsStream)
    .map( (value, action) => value);

/**
 * Provides a stream of address retrieved from a postcode lookup
 * @type {Array}
 */
export let AddressStream = PostCodeLookupStream
    .flatMapLatest( postcode =>  MyAPI.postcodeLookup( postcode ) )
    .flatMap( response => response.json() )
    .shareReplay(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `withLatestFrom`. I don't know why it took me so long to find that in the docs, but it did.

```
/**
 * Provides a stream of POSTCODE_LOOKUP events
 * e.g: A stream of postcodes.
 * @type {Object} a mouse event
 */
export let PostcodeLookupIntentsStream = Actions.stream
    .filter( action => action.key === KEYS.POSTCODE_LOOKUP );

/**
 * Provides a stream of values from a  post code input field
 * @type {String}
 */
export let PostCodeValueStream = Actions.stream
    .filter( action => action.key === KEYS.POSTCODE_CHANGE )
    .map( action => action.payload.postcode )
    .shareReplay(1);


/**
 * Combines `PostcodeLookupIntentsStream` and `PostCodeValueStream` to
 * produce a stream of postcode values. New postcode values are emitted
 * every time an event is emitted from the            
 * `PostcodeLookupIntentsStream`
 */
export let PostCodeLookupValueStream = PostcodeLookupIntentsStream
    .withLatestFrom( PostCodeValueStream, (action, value) => value  );


/**
 * Provides a stream of address retrieved from a postcode lookup
 * @type {Array}
 */
export let AddressStream = PostCodeLookupStream
    .flatMapLatest( postcode => return MyAPI.postcodeLookup( postcode ) )
    .flatMap( response => response.json() )
    .shareReplay(1);
```